# How to validate dynamic sections of form using jquery validate

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c7e6v/). I am dynamically adding a div containing an input element (in real app there are multiple fields). When I click Submit, it just validates the first and not dynamically added HTML elements. I am making sure the dynamic elements have unique ids.

Any thoughts?

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {    
    e.preventDefault();
    validator = $("#myForm").validate({
        rules: {
            name: "required"
        }
    });
    $("#myForm").valid();
});
```

**Update**:-
I noticed something peculiar. After I add a new input element, and then focused on this new input and click submit, I can see in firebug, that jquery automatically adds a "class=error" to this input tag w/o showing the error message. And if i try writing something to the second input, it removes the error message from the first.

Comment: I am using jquery 2.0 and jquery validate 1.11.1

Comment: You should not have two text inputs with the same `name`. That value is supposed to be unique. Your validation rules will only match the first occurrence of `name=name`.

Comment: See this fiddle as an example of using different values in your validation rules paired with different input names: http://jsfiddle.net/h4VuD/

Comment: Hmm, I thought only id has to be unique and not any other attribute? Isn't this a bug/bad implementation of the plugin?

But in my case I can add multiple input tags, I cannot exactly do it as per your method, since I won't know the id in advance. Do I have to do "dynamically" add the rules, 

$('[name=fname]').rules("add", "required") or is there a better way?

Comment: It's no bug.  The documentation clearly states that each input must contain a `name` attribute in order for the plugin to function properly.  There would be no logical point with this constraint if all were the same.

Comment: @TravisJ - Thanks for the info, if you can add that as answer I will mark that. 
@Sparky - Thanks, maybe I shouldnt have used bug, but I feel the implementation can be improved to validate by default all elements with matching `name`

Comment: @parsh - Thanks for the consideration, but my comment was only that. I don't feel that it constitutes an answer. However, I am happy you reached a solution to your issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your markup to this (your submit button was outside of the form tag)

```
<form id="myForm">
    <div id="section">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="required"/>
    </div>
    <input type="button" id="add" value="add" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

and inside your jQuery onready you have this

```
var count = 0;
$("#myForm").validate();
$('#add').on('click', function () {
    var section = $('#section').clone(false).attr('id', function () {
        return 'section' + (count);
    });
    section.find('input').attr('name', function () {
        return 'name' + (count);
    });
    section.find('label').attr('for', function () {
        return 'name' + (count);
    });
    section.insertAfter('#section');
    count++;
});
```

This gives you what you need:

1. each input with a unique name
2. the label matching the corresponding input field

[updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/c7e6v/2/)

Comment: Thanks. I was able to figure out the soln after @TravisJ mentioned about the `name` attribute. If he doesnt convert that to answer, I will mark yours as the answer. Anyways +1 for a "cleaner" implementation than mine.